# Sunset dates for Office Add-ins using IE11 and Legacy Edge

Tags: internet-explorer-11, office-js

We'd like to know when support ends for IE11 and Legacy Edge as the office add-in renderer.

This article doesn't really say:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins

Just that app source will be testing for it.  Is there an end date in sight for this?

Comment: I agree with Rick's answer, no end date is set now officially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No end date has been set. But you can design your add-in to "gracefully fail" on these browsers. See [Support IE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/support-ie-11#determine-at-runtime-if-the-add-in-is-running-in-internet-explorer).